# ImportError: cannot import name 'keras_tensor' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I'm getting this error while loading the tensorflow addons library

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

ImportError: cannot import name 'keras_tensor' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine'
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This error is because you have **incompatibility** issues between your **TensorFlow**, **Python** and **tensorflow-addons**. Uninstall the tensorflow-addons and install the version based on the table below. Refer the [Github repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons) for more information.

[image: compatibility]